# Get data from column of a table and store to column another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables. The first one is `filedetails`, and the second is `filestate`.

The `filedetails` table is as follows:

```
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
| id | NAME     |  description | data   |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+
|                                       |
+----+----------+-----+--------+--+-----+
```

The `filestate` table is as follows:

```
+---------+------+-----------+
|filename | size | download  | 
+---------+------+-----------+
|                            |
+----+----------+-----+------+
```

How can I insert a `name` column value from `filedetails` table into the filename column of `filestate` with PHP?

For example, if a new record adds a value to the `name` column in `filedetails` table it should automatically be added to the `filename` column in `filestate`.

Comment: you can create `after insert trigger` on `filedetails` table which will insert data in `filestate` table.

Comment: @Code-Monk, thank you can you please give me code for my case

Answer (score 0):

PHP and MySQL I would recommend you use PDO.  MySQLi is slightly easier to start off with, but PDO is better in the long run and can be more secure.  But the syntax for PDO would be something like

```
public static function someFunctionName($name) {
    $stmt = self::getInstance()->prepare("INSERT INTO <yourTablename> SET name = :name");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return;
}
```

Then, the copy to another table you do within MySQL itself with an after_event trigger.  information on this can be found here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: thank you, but your code isnt clearly for me what is your mean SET name = :name. and can you give me MySQL code for my case.

Comment: the SET name = :name is the PDO syntax.  :name is the variable defined on the next line down with the bindParam statement.

Comment: i still need help, my problem not solved please give me a clear MySQL code example

Comment: It isnt just mysql code you need if you are wanting to do this through PHP.  You need to either use mysqli or PDO to link PHP and MySQl database together.